# Unity 2018.3, linker crashes during il2cpp compilation on Android (ndk n16b) after upgrading to Catalina

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-ndk, il2cpp

After upgrading to macOS Catalina, my Unity 2018.3 fails to compile for Android using il2cpp.

The error seems to happen during the linking process.

Here's the output:

```
/Users/myuser/Applications/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ @"/var/folders/vq/04653nwj79jdpld6_lndr1lw0000gn/T/tmpXtN5uB.tmp" -o "/Users/myuser/Documents/Unity/MyProject/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/linkresult_44B2FEF258539B2B7FE0DE0B1C88B423/libil2cpp.so" -shared -Wl,-soname,libil2cpp.so -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--build-id --sysroot "/Users/myuser/Applications/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64" -gcc-toolchain "/Users/myuser/Applications/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64" -target aarch64-none-linux-android -Wl,--wrap,sigaction -L "/Users/myuser/Applications/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/arm64-v8a" -lgnustl_static -llog -Xlinker -Map="/Users/myuser/Documents/Unity/MyProject/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/linkresult_44B2FEF258539B2B7FE0DE0B1C88B423/libil2cpp.map" -rdynamic -fuse-ld=bfd
clang++: error: invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=bfd'
```

Looks like in the NDK there is no linker `ld-bfd` for darwin-x86_64 :(

Do you have any idea on how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a (really bad) workaround, that... works.

Navigate to your NDK folder, then:

`cd toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/aarch64-linux-android/bin`

Now, copy the `gold` linker as `bfd`:

`cp ld.gold ld.bfd`

Not sure if it has any side effect, but, well... it compiles!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the API Compatibility Level in File / Build Settings / Player Settings to .NET Standard 2.0 solved the problem for me.